# Xamarin.Forms MediaPlugin stop video recording

Tags: xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms app takes video using MediaPlugin however i want to stop video recording and get video file after some time. I tried to start a timer and after 30 seconds stop video but could not succeed it.

Is there any way to stop video recording without clicking any button?

Comment: please provide answer if you have

Comment: you can use desiredLength property:                                                          new StoreVideoOptions
                        {
                            SaveToAlbum = true,
                            Directory = "myappname",
                            CompressionQuality = 20,
                            Quality = VideoQuality.Medium,
                            DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear,
                            DesiredLength = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                        });

Comment: i have add  DesiredLength = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) but not working

Comment: It has worked for me :/

Comment: let me check again

Comment: my Code:
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
            {
                Name = "video.mp4",
                Directory = "DefaultVideos",
                DesiredLength = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
            });

Comment: i have check in android device but it's not working